# Required DLLs/OCX/Other Files for Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have one application installer that uses crystal report for reporting. However since the installer does not have any crystal report related dll/ocx or other files, I am not able to run the application.

Can you please tell all the dependency files for Crystal Report ? I already tried to copy over Crpe32.dll, Crystal32.ocx but no success.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Anurag

Answer (score 0):

You can download the run time for crystal report from the SAP website and run it.

[Crystal Reports VS 2008](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-27917)
[Crystal Reports VS 2005 & 2008](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-27942)